# cannot convert to a pointer type : C error

Tags: c++, c

I have a function that I need to call

```
int (*trytoprint_f)(int val, void *param);
```

but when I call this function, and put

```
str name = {"jack", 4};
int age = 2;

client->trytoprint(age, (void *)name));
```

it gives me an error of "cannot convert to a pointer type : C error"

I know the solution which is basically use a function below
str_dup_ptr(name,  ulr->imsi, mem); and it works (I got this function from a framework).

Anyways, I am just confused. So the question is if the function accepts (void *param), and I declare name variable with type str, howso when I cast this "name" variable into void pointer, it returns me this error?

Can anyone help me in understanding why this error happens?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to convert a pointer to structure to void* not a structure itself. Try this way

```
client->trytoprint(age, (void *) &name));
```

Comment: yes. it works, but would you mind telling me why not just casting, but also I need the address of it? thanks so much!! @the.malkolm

Comment: If you simply cast to a `void *`, you are in essence trying to call (in C++) the `operator void *()` function in the `str` class (as far as I understand, anyhow). Probably not quite what you want to do; since you want to pass a void * _pointer_ you need to first take the address (getting a pointer of type `str *`) and then cast it to a pointer of type `void *`.